# Why parallel resistor for oscillator?

Tags: crystal

I have a design with a W65C51S ACIA IC, which uses a 1,8 crystal MHz for serial communication. The clock generation example in the datasheet shows an external 1 MOhms resistor in parallel to the crystal.

[image]

It seems that the crystal doesn´t produce any clock signal if the resistor is missing. So what does this resistor do?

Comment: It provides a DC bias path (necessary in some oscillators).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [datasheet](http://www.westerndesigncenter.com/wdc/documentation/w65c51s.pdf) of the W65C51S doesn't provide enough details to be sure but my guess is that the crystal oscillator circuit inside the IC doesn't have a 1 M ohm feedback resistor.

This is a typical example of a commonly used crystal oscillator circuit:

[image]

This is a [Pierce oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pierce_oscillator) circuit.

My guess is that on the W65C51S the feedback resistor \$R_f\$ isn't implemented.
It might have been impossible or too costly to do so. So an external resistor is needed.

The function of the resistor is to **DC bias** the inverter such that it has a **high gain** (large amplification) which is needed to make the oscillator work.

Comment: Thank you, that´s the missing point. Can you please add some explanation of why the inverter has a high gain when there is some kind of DC bias on his input/output? I would suggest that the gain is much bigger when you input some small voltage and get the Vcc output. But maybe I misunderstand this point...

Comment: Negative DC feedback via the resistor keeps the input optimally biased to produce maximum gain @Kampi

Comment: *Can you please add some explanation of why the inverter has a high gain when there is some kind of DC bias on his input/output?* I could but you can also study the CMOS inverter circuit in more detail yourself. It is a very common circuit and there are many explanations to be found of you just look for them. Perhaps this is of help: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fqiYu6IOtmU

Comment: Thank you for the video. As far as I understand it after watching the video (only the first half till now) you bias the inverter to let the crystal oscillate between a voltage of Vcc / 2. In this case, the crystal only has to apply a small voltage to let the inverter swing between maximum and minimum with the oscillator frequency.